# Не работает footable

Tags: javascript, html, css, footable

У меня есть JSP страничка, на которую (не целевую пока что, тестовую) я хочу добавить таблицу footable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_css/res_css_jquery/jquery.ui.all.css" type="text/css"  media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_css/res_css_jquery/jquery.multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_script/res_script_jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_script/res_script_jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_script/res_script_jquery/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_script/res_script_jquery/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_script/res_script_jquery/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/engine.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/util.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/interface/FamilyClientHighLevelMainClass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/interface/FamilyClientHighLevelSystemInformationClass.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dwr/interface/FamilyClientHighLevelOptionalClass.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_css/res_css_family/IntPage.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_css/res_css_family/demo_table.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_css/res_css_family/templatemo_style.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_script/res_script_family/generalscript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_script/res_script_family/mainpagefunction.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.standalone.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_components/table/footable/css/footable.editing.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.filtering.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.paging.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.sorting.css" type="text/css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_components/table/footable/js/footable.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_components/table/footable/js/footable.editing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_components/table/footable/js/footable.export.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_components/table/footable/js/footable.filtering.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_components/table/footable/js/footable.paging.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_components/table/footable/js/footable.sorting.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="res_components/table/footable/js/footable.state.js"></script>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <BODY>
    <table style="border-spacing: 0px(0px);padding:0" border=0>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:0;vertical-align:top; min-width:340px">
            <div id="templatemo_wrapper" style="min-width:340px">
              <div id="templatemo_sidebar">
                <div id="site_title" style="margin-bottom: 20px">

                </div>
                <!-- end of site_title -->
                <div class="sidebar_box" style="padding-bottom: 15px">
                  <h3 style="margin-top: 0">Специалист:</h3>
                  <span id="Ispolnitel" style="padding-bottom: 0"></span>
                  <span id="ispolnitelhide" style="display:none;">></span>
                  <span id="role"></span>
                </div>
                <div id="MainPage-sidebar">
                  <div class="sidebar_box" id="statisticdiv">
                    <h3>Статистика</h3>
                      <div class="sidebar_content" >
                        <ul id="statistic"
                        style="adding:0;padding-left:5px;margin:0;
                        list-style-type:none;">
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="sidebar_box">
                    <h3>О компании</h3>
                      <div class="sidebar_content">
                        <ul id="news_box">
                          <li class="last">
                            <p style="font-weight: bold;
                            font-size: 14px;margin: 0 0 0 0;
                            padding: 0; font-color: #333">

                            </p>
                            <p>

                            </p>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
          </td>
          <td id="contenttd" style="vertical-align:top;padding:0;min-width:850px;max-width:100%">
            <div id="templatemo_content">
              <div id="templatemo_menu">
                <ul>
                  <li id="MainID"><a id="mainqid" href="#">Главная</a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- class="current" -->
                  <li id="FindID"><a id="findqid" href="#">Поиск</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="GraphicID"><a id="graphicqid" href="#">Графики</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id='ReportsID'><a id="reportsqid" href="#">Отчёты</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id='documentsid'><a href="#" id="documentsqid">Документы</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id='ImportID'><a id="importqid" href="#">Импорт</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id='InfoID'><a href="#" id="infousers">Информация</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id='CloseID'><a id="closeqid" href="#">Выход</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="cleaner"></div>
              </div>
              <!-- end of templatemo_menu -->

              <div class="content_box">
                <div id="MainPage">
                </div>

                <!-- Здесь добавляется таблица -->
                <table class="footable"></table>

                <div id="clear"></div>
              </div>
              <br/>
            </div>
            <div class="cleaner"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="templatemo_footer_wrapper">
      <div id="templatemo_footer">
        <p id="versioninfo">
        </p>
      </div>
      <!-- end of templatemo_footer -->
    </div>
  </BODY>
</html>
```

Код manepagefunction.js:

```
$(document).ready
(
    function()
    {       
        $('#MainID').click(mainidclick);
        $('#FindID').click(findidclick);
        $('#GraphicID').click(graphicidclick);
        $('#ReportsID').click(reportsidclick);
        $('#InfoID').click(infoidclick);
        $('#ImportID').click(importidclick);
        $('#documentsid').click(documentsidclick);      
        $("#CloseID").click(closeidclick);

        // Этот метод
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.footable').footable({
                "expandFirst": true,
                "columns": [
                    { "name": "id", "title": "№" },
                    { "name": "name", "title": "Ф.И.О." },
                    { "name": "district", "title": "Район" },
                    { "name": "comment", "title": "Комментарий"}
                ],
                "rows": [
                    { "id": 1, "name": "Зонов Богдан Игоревич", "district": "г. Киров", "comment": "Отсутствует СНИЛС"},
                    { "id": 2, "name": "Смирнова Кристина Андреевна", "district": "г. Киров", "comment": "Активное в 2 районах"}
                ]
            });
        });
    }
);
/*
 * Статистика на главной странице.
 */
function getApplicationStatistics()
{
    FamilyClientHighLevelSystemInformationClass.getApplicationStatistics
    (
        {
            callback : function(str) 
            {
                $("#statistic").html(str);
            },
            exceptionHandler:InvokerMethodExceptionHandler
        }   
    );
};
function getApplicationMainFormInformation(Login)
{
    FamilyClientHighLevelSystemInformationClass.getApplicationMainFormInformation
    (
        Login,
        {
            callback : function(str) 
            {
                $("#MainPage").empty();
                $("#MainPage").append(str);
            },
            exceptionHandler:InvokerMethodExceptionHandler
        }
    );
}
```

И при загрузке страницы появляются ошибки:

```
main.jsp:40 GET http://localhost:8081/FamilyC/res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.filtering.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.jsp:41 GET http://localhost:8081/FamilyC/res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.paging.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.jsp:42 GET http://localhost:8081/FamilyC/res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.sorting.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.jsp:40 GET http://localhost:8081/FamilyC/res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.filtering.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.jsp:42 GET http://localhost:8081/FamilyC/res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.sorting.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
main.jsp:41 GET http://localhost:8081/FamilyC/res_components/table/footable/css/footable.core.paging.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
mainpagefunction.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).footable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (mainpagefunction.js:15)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3260)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:3472)
    at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:3503)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все было просто, подключение jQuery перенести выше нужно было и все заработало. Мастера footable отпишите пожалуйста в комментариях.